# Alternative Document Method

Tags: javascript, if-statement, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

Summarize the problem.

1. The goal of this program is to determine if the users integer is even or odd.
2. I believe my code could be more concise.
3. There is a logical error that states that the HTML Input Element is undefined.

Describe what you've tried.

1. I changed the `document.getElementById()` to the `.querySelector()` and `.getElementByClassName`.

Code -

https://jsfiddle.net/pherami1/jfh3xq69/2/

```
const input = document.getElementById('textInput');<br>
const button = document.getElementById('submitButton');<br>
    
button.addEventListener('click', evenOrOdd);

function evenOrOdd () {
    let result;
    let even;
    let odd;
    
    if (input % 2) {
        result = even;
    } else {
        result = odd;
    }
    document.getElementById('para').textContent = input + " is an " + result + " number.";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things that you need to change -

First thing - If you want to get the value of input, use `.value`.

Second - Declare the `input` inside the `evenOrOdd` function. If you don't do so, then the value of input will not be changed every time you click the button.

Third - The output of `.value` is a string, but to find whether a number is even or odd, we need to convert the string to a number using `Number()`.

Fourth - When you check for a number to be even or odd, you change the value of the `result` variable to `even` or `odd`. `even` and `odd` are variables, not strings. So, whatever the value of `result` is, it is always going to be `undefined` since `even` and `odd` are undefined. Change the value of `result` to strings `"even"` or `"odd"`.

Fifth - When you check for even numbers, you do `(input % 2)`. If the number is even, then `(input % 2)` will evaluate to `0`. 0 means false. So, even if your number is even, you will get "odd". Change the if condition to `(input % 2 == 0)`

All these changes are applied in the below snippet. Check the snippet's code -

```js
let button = document.getElementById('submitButton');
button.addEventListener('click', evenOrOdd);

function evenOrOdd () {
    //Declare the input inside the function and use .value to get the value and Number() to convert the string to number.
    let input = Number(document.getElementById('textInput').value);
    let result;
    
    //Change the condition
    if (input % 2 == 0) {
        result = "even";//Change to strings, not variables
    } else {
        result = "odd";
    }
    document.getElementById('para').textContent = input + " is an " + result + "number.";
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="textInput" />
<button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
<p id="para"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you Praneet, I appreciate it.